# What´s the meaning of this exception and how can I solve it?

Tags: winjs

I´m working in a Windows App but when I want to add a toolTip I get this exception: HierarchyRequestError. I´ve checked if all my tags are properly typed and it seems that there is no problem with them. Any ideas?

```
<div id="wrapper" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Tooltip" data-win-options="{contentElement:'info'}">
       <img src="images/news.jpg" alt="Donald Trump">
</div>
<section class="info-wrapper">
      <div id="info">    
           <video controls src="videos/info.wmv"></video>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I can´t use a dash. I changed it for an underscore and it worked.